# how to increase height and width by values entered by the user

Tags: java, jgrasp

see the add method in the class for this question.

How do i increse the input for height and width by amounts entered by the user.

```
public class Bounce
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
//declare variables
  Oblong myOblong = new Oblong();
  double h = 0;
  double w = 0;
  Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print(" Enter the Height: ");
  h = keyboardIn.nextInt();
  System.out.print(" Enter the Width: ");
  w = keyboardIn.nextInt();

  myOblong.setHeight(h);
  myOblong.setWidth(w);

  System.out.println("Width: "+myOblong.getWidth());
  System.out.println("Height: "+myOblong.getHeight());
  System.out.print("Area: "+myOblong.calculateArea());
  System.out.print("Add: "+myOblong.add());



  public class Oblong
 {
// instance variables
private double height;
private double width;

// constructor
public Oblong(){

    height = 0.0;
    width = 0.0;
}

// methods
public double getHeight()
{   
    return height;      
}

public double getWidth()
{   
    return width;       
}

public void setWidth(double w)
{   
    width = w;
}

public void setHeight(double h)
{   
    height = h;
}

public double calculateArea()
{   
    return width * height;
}   

public void add(double w, double h)
{
  height = height+h;
  width = width+w;
}

}// end of class
```

the add method above is the one i need to call and use to increase the height and width by a value entered by the user.

When i compile the bounce class it gives me an error for the add it says add in oblong cannot be applied to ().

Don't know how to fix any help would be great.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: The error is telling you all you need to know. You've declared the method to take two parameters, `public void add(double w, double h)`, and you're passing in **none**, `myOblong.add()`. That doesn't make sense to the compiler (or to me).

Comment: Your `add` function has parameters, but when you call it in your main function, you don't pass in any parameters.